# Horizontal space between chapter number and title in book

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am writing a document with the `book`class and a redefined `\thechapter`command. Since I have a lot of chapters, the chapter number and the chapter title overlap in the TOC. How can I change the horizontal space between them? I have only seen solutions that do not work for the `book`class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{I.\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Number your chapters in base 16? :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reserve some space for the numbers in advance by `\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}`, for example, after loading the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{I.\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\chapter{AAA}
\end{document}
```